# Django Rest Framework custom token authentication

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want a custom authentication which will authenticate the token in my model.I have a model called User_Auth where there is a field called 'secret_token'. I want the Django Rest Framework to Authenticate token through that model.
I had followed the docs on django rest framework website but didnt work for me.
Please help me to solve this issue.

models.py

```
class User_Auth(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secret_token = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
```

authentication.py

```
class UserAuthentication(authentication.TokenAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        secret_token = request.META.get('Authorization')

        if not secret_token:
            return None
        
        try:
            ua = User_Auth.objects.get(secret_token=secret_token)
        except User_Auth.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Unauthorized')

        return (ua, None)
```

views.py

```
class User(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (UserAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

I am passing the token through the Header.

```
Authorization: 'a7c14fc808b58533e4d1651cd2375c3b41a38ef5d120254a1cb4bbd90b3be1534215516b023818e4'
```

Its Returning this error

```
'User_Auth' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'
```

Please help me.

Comment: ua = User_Auth.objects.get(secret_token=secret_token) should that line not be ua = User_Auth.objects.get(secret_token=key)?

Comment: Same error is returning after the changes

Comment: test it with a curl command. like this.     curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token a7c14fc808b58533e4d1651cd2375c3b41a38ef5d120254a1cb4bbd90b3be1534215516b023818e4'

Comment: Also it seems the line if not secret_token: return None is not working

Comment: if not secret_token: return None was a command in the docs of django rest framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `is_authenticated` property in `User_Auth` model. This is a read only attribute and always return `True` for a valid user. Django's `User` class has this attribute and internally it has been used for authentication.

So to resolve the error add this attribute in `User_Auth` class like following.

```
class User_Auth(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User_Master, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    secret_token = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        """
        Always return True. This is a way to tell if the user has been
        authenticated in templates.
        """
        return True
```